# Keep the DropDownList selected value the same as the value shown in the GridView

Tags: asp.net

I am using a ListView to show the table. I change one of the field in the  to a dropdownlist so that when I click on "Edit" button, that field will be a dropdown with all the values already populate in it. My problem is that when I click on the "Edit" the dropdownlist's selected value will change to the first value of the dropdown rather than the previous value that shows in the ListView. How could I control this to make the selected value same as the one showed originally. Thanks. I would be happy to make any clarifications if the question is not clear.

Here is my EditItemTemplate:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color: #999999;">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="DieTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Die") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="TempelPart" DataValueField="TempelPart" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ObsoleteCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Obsolete") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="column1Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("column1") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `SelectedValue` of the DropDownList just like you do for your CheckBoxes and Labels.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
  DataTextField="TempelPart"
  DataValueField="TempelPart"
  ViewStateMode="Enabled"
  SelectedValue='<%# Eval("YOUR_COLUMN") %>'
</asp:DropDownList>
```